# How to get all revisions in subversion URL (trunk/branch) based on a string in svn comments?

Tags: bash, shell, svn, revisions

Need some help on shell command to get all revs in subversion trunk URL based on a string in svn comments.

I figured out to get it on one file but not on URL.

I tried `svn log URL --stop-on-copy` and `svn log URL --xml` to get the revs but unsuccessful.

Thanks !!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I have no problems (with 1.7) getting the complete set of log messages specific to any subtree via URL.

Comment: I meant how to get only those revs based on a string in svn comments - like a ticket number. I tried piping to "svn log URL --stop-on-copy" and "svn log URL --xml" ..

Comment: So "doesn't work" means "I can't extract what I need from the multi-line output of `svn log`"? In that case, I'm guessing that *Sithsu*'s command-line string will do what you want (haven't tried it). Unfortunately, `svn log` doesn't give you an option to generate your own format.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `sed`. It's probably not perfect but it also works with multiline comments. Replace `SEARCH_STRING` for your personal search.

```
svn log -l100 | sed -n '/^r/{h;d};/SEARCH_STRING/{g;s/^r\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For Subversion 1.8 it's

`svn log URL --search STRING`

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
x="refactoring"; svn log --limit 10 | egrep -i --color=none "($x|^r[0-9]+ \|.*lines$)" | egrep -B 1 -i --color=none $x | egrep --color=none "^r[0-9]+ \|.*lines$" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^r//g'
```

Replace `refactoring` with search string.
Change `svn log` parameters to suite your need.
Case insensitive matching is used (`egrep -i`).

---

Edit based on comment.

```
x="ILIES-113493"; svn log | egrep -i --color=none "($x|^r[0-9]+ \|.*lines$)" | egrep -B 1 -i --color=none $x | egrep --color=none "^r[0-9]+ \|.*lines$" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^r//g'
```

Notes:

- `x` is the variable to contain the search string, and `x` is used in
  two places in the command.
- In order to use `x` as a variable in the shell itself, you need to put entire command on a single line (from `x=".."; svn log ... sed '...'`). Semicolon `;` can be used to separate multiple commands on the same line.
- I had used `--limit 10` in example to limit the number of log entries,
  change that as well as use other `svn log` parameters to suite your
  need. Using `--limit 10` will restrict the search to 10 most recent log entries.

Comment: @iaav Updated answer. Couple of problems in the way you tried it. 1) space after ticket number in first egrep. 2) x is used in second egrep as well, should have replaced it with ticket number also. 3) `--limit 10` will give only most recent 10 entries. I used it to test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help !! This worked for me:

```
svn log $URL --stop-on-copy | grep -B 2 $STRING | grep "^r" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1

Use "--stop-on-copy" or "--limit" options depending on the requirement.
```